# How to write a condition in a function to make this comment Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

How to write a condition in a function to make this comment "Please provide two integers or floats"
Now I have a ValueError like " could not convert string or float "

```
def divede():

   num1 = float(input("Enter first number:"))
   num2 = float(input("Enter second number:"))
   return num1, num2


num1, num2 = divede()

while True:
   if num2 == []:
       print("Please provide two integers or floats")

   elif num2 != 0:

       print(f"{num1} / {num2} is {num1/num2}")
       break

   else:

       print("Please do not divede by zero")
       num1, num2 = divede()

def divede():

   num1 = float(input("Enter first number:"))
   num2 = float(input("Enter second number:"))
   return num1, num2


num1, num2 = divede()

while True:
   if num2 == []:
       print("Please provide two integers or floats")

   elif num2 != 0:

       print(f"{num1} / {num2} is {num1/num2}")
       break

   else:

       print("Please do not divede by zero")
       num1, num2 = divede()
```

here I have a problem:

```
while True:
   if num2 == []: # wrong condition
       print("Please provide two integers or floats")
```

Thx for all answers

Comment: When you take input from the user, use try...except blocks. So when the user enters a string instead of an int or float, an exception is thrown. Handle it with  print("Please provide two integers or floats")

Comment: `num2` is a `float` and `[]` is a `list`. By default, python doesn't know how you want to resolve that comparison

Comment: As you already did conversion to `float` when getting `num2`, there is no need to check if it is empty. If it was, you would get the `ValueError` in the input itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get arises as soon as you try to convert your string input to float in one of the following lines:

```
num1 = float(input("Enter first number:"))
num2 = float(input("Enter second number:"))
```

I would suggest you change your divede function to the following:

```
def divede():
    while True:
        try:
            num1 = float(input("Enter first number:"))
            num2 = float(input("Enter second number:"))
            return num1, num2
        except(ValueError):
            print("Please provide two integers or floats")
```

The while loop makes sure that the user is asked for repeating input until he actually provides two numbers. 
The except(ValueError) is there to catch only the specific errors you want.
Then you also need to change the rest of the script like so:

```
while True:
    if num2 != 0:

        print(f"{num1} / {num2} is {num1 / num2}")
        break

    else:

        print("Please do not divede by zero")
        num1, num2 = divede()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your division function to this:

```
def divede():

   num1 = input("Enter first number:")
   num2 = input("Enter second number:")
   try:
       num1, num2 = float(num1), float(num2)
   except ValueError:
       print("Invalid entry, please enter numbers")
       return divede()
   return num1, num2
```

In that case you do not need the first `if` in your `while` loop.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't `except ValueError` instead of doing a catch all? Seems like bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

My code is too complicate :) 
correct answer is :

```
def divide(a,b):
    try:
        total = a / b
    except TypeError:
        return "Please provide two integers or floats"
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "Please do not divide by zero"
    return total
```